# Sorting a linked list alphabetically

Tags: c

I'm trying to sort a singly linked list alphabetically, I think I have the concept down but I'm getting a compilation error that says:

```
function.c: error: assignment to expression with array type newNode->text = newNode->next->text;
```

It also says the same for the line `node->next->text = temp;` The data that goes into each node of the linked list is taken from input, and say for this scenario there are 5 nodes. My code is below:

```
// the struct used for representing a linked-list node
typedef struct writeText{
    char text[100];
    struct writeText *next;
}write;

void sorting(write ** front, write ** rear) {
    char  *temp;
    write *newNode;
    newNode = *front;
    
    if(newNode) {
        while(newNode && newNode->next) {
            if(strcmp(newNode->text, newNode->next->text) > 0) {
                temp = newNode->text;
                newNode->text = newNode->next->text;
                newNode->next->text = temp;
            }
            newNode= newNode->next;
        }
    }
}
```

So how do I sort my linked list alphabetically? Thanks

Comment: `writeText::text` is not a pointer. It's an array. You'll need to manually copy the data from one `char` array to another.

Comment: I assume the intent wasn't to declare an instance `write` of structure `writeText`, and the *real* code has the missing `typedef` you chose to omit for before `struct`. This would fail to compile as shown for that reason alone, much less trying to direct-assign arrays by value later.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't catch that when transferring my code, I do have it in my code though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot copy arrays by assignment. For strings, use `strcpy` or `strncpy`. For other arrays, use `memcpy` or `memmove`.

Change:

```
temp = newNode->text;
newNode->text = newNode->next->text;
newNode->next->text = temp;
```

to

```
strcpy(temp, newNode->next);
strcpy(newNode->text, newNode->next->text);
strcpy(newNode->next->text, temp);
```

Comment: There is another error that appears on the line beneath on "node->next->user = temp;" that says "error: assignment to expression with array type", how would I fix that?